# How to run react application using webpack-dev-server?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

when I run the command webpack-dev-server --open --mode development, I get the output as shown in the image. I don't know what to do? I have been stuck in this for a few hours now. 
but when I prepare the building using the following command webpack --mode production and open the index.html file from dist folder it runs fine in the browser.

[image: when I run the command webpack-dev-server --open --mode development, I get the output as shown in the image]

My package.json file

```
{
    "name": "rapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "react app",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run build",
        "build": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
        "build:prod": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "learning",
        "react"
    ],
    "author": "Rafay Hassan",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "react": "^16.8.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-loader": "^7.*",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "3.0.7",
        "webpack": "^4.29.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
    }
}
```

Comment: use create-react-app

Comment: I am new to react and I want to learn it with webpack configuration

Comment: Create index.js in your root directory